# Decompressing gzipstream from

Tags: c#, sockets, gzip, compression

I've made a simple proxy server. Works fine, but not the gzip decompressing:

1. The magic number is not correct. Be sure .
2. No error, but the gzipstream won't decompress.

It works as follows:

```
private void HandleTraffic()
{
    while ((bytesRead = realServer.Receive(buffer, 0, BODYBUFFERSIZE, SocketFlags.None)) > 0)
    {
        decompressedBuffer = new byte[BODYBUFFERSIZE];
        if (t == "gzip")
        {

            MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream(), inputStream = new MemoryStream();
            inputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            inputStream.Position = 0;
            inputStream.Flush();
            using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                gz.CopyTo(outputStream);
            }

            decompressedBuffer = outputStream.ToArray();

            MessageBox.Show(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(decompressedBuffer));
        }
    }
}
```

InputStream is filled, but outputStream isn't decompressed or gives me the error 'The magic number is not correct'.

In this job, sockets has been required.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but are you sure you're receiving the right input data? I've run into issues by trying to unzip data that had some custom headers before the data.

Comment: Thank you xxbbcc. I read to \r\n\r\n. That's the header, isn't it? After that, i'm going further with the body. Non-gzip requests work perfect.

A lot of examples are with compress and decompress files. But this is from an internet host. I really don't know :-(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to process the data in a proxy server in any way whatsoever, unzipping, deflating, whatsoever. Just copy the bytes. The only data you need to even look at is the first line from the client, the HTTP CONNECT command.

Comment: EJP, thank you.

I know about copying the bytes. But: gzipped data will result in a 'download as octetstream' message.

Is there a difference between copying 'compressed data' and 'uncompressed data'?

(i'm using ASCIIENcoding: is that the problem?)

Comment: EJP, do you mean passing the bytes to the socket? It doesn't work like expected.

Comment: @JeroenBokier There is no difference between coping data and copying data. The data includes the headers and the request body, and it doesn't matter what the headers say, or how the body is encoded. Just copy the bytes and you cannot go wrong. If its going wrong, you aren't doing it right.

Comment: To be honest, this post doesn't help at all.  I'm getting the same error, and I have no clue why.

Comment: You can't possibly be getting the same error if you just copy the bytes when the error you were getting was a decompression error. *Remove* the decompression code!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this for myself was to turn off Fiddler.